# How can I add commas to a string of numbers in Applescript?

Tags: string, macos, parsing, applescript

In Applescript I have a string of single digit numbers:

```
0123456789
```

I want to go through that string and add a comma between each number, so it would show:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

How can I do this with Applescript?

Notes

- I want both the input and output to be of type "string" - not list.
- The numbers will always be single digit numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
set theNumber to "3452678190"
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ","
set theItems to every character of theNumber as string
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
return theItems
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a handy feature called [`AppleScript's text item delimiters`](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24725), which allows you to break up (or "parse" in computer jargon) text into segments, and then extract data from those segments. They are the separators of text items in a piece of text. A simple example:

```
set prevTIDs to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set theString to "Don't-eat-the-yellow-snow"
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "-" --tell AppleScript to break up strings at each occurrence of a hyphen '-' in a given string
set these_items to every text item of theString
//--> {"Don't", "eat", "the", "yellow", "snow"}

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to prevTIDs
return these_items
```

It is always considered good practice when working with text item delimiters to restore the original delimiters; once you change the delimiters, they will **globally affect** the running environment until the process is closed and restarted.

Another use for text item delimiters is replacing words or characters in a given string:

```
set prevTIDs to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set theString to "Don't eat the yellow snow"
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "yellow" --the word you want to replace
set temp to every text item of theString
//--> {"Don't eat the", "snow"}

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "pink" --the replacement word
set theString to temp as string
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to prevTIDs
return theString
//--> "Don't eat the pink snow"
```

However, note that this replaces **every** occurrence of the word "yellow". The reason I'm saying this is consider the following string:

```
If someone added one plus one, what would be the result?
```

If you wanted to replace the word "one" with the word "two", you would have to be sure to precede "two" with a space when creating the new delimiter, or your resulting string would be the following:

```
If sometwo added two plus two, what would be the result?
```

---

What you're trying to do is basically replacing empty strings with commas. All you need to do is follow these simple steps to do this:

1. Create a variable to store the current delimiters in
2. Create a variable to store your string in
3. Change the delimiter to an empty string `""`
4. Coerce your string into a list (i.e. `set the list to every text item of yourString`)
5. Change the delimiter to a comma `,`
6. Coerce your newly created list back into a string (i.e. `set yourString to list as string`)
7. Restore the old delimiters
8. `return` your string

The resulting code:

```
set prevTIDs to AppleScript's text item delimtiers
set myString to "0123456789"
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
set the_list to every text item of myString
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ","
set myString to the_list as string
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to prevTIDs
return myString
```

Happy coding! :)